String with `!` followed by `:` in batch script with SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
I have a script which uses SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and takes user input. This is a problem if an input string has ! and then :, as these characters and everything in between are removed.
Example: I enter a!b:c with user input into x and save it directly into the script as y and z.
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET x=
SET /P x=
SET y=a!b:c
SET "z=a!b:c"
echo %x% %y% %z%

The result is ac ac ac. How can I fix this for strings entered directly like y and z, and how can I fix it for user input like x?

Don't use SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION until after you have used SET /P x=.

BUT always use a setlocal of some variety directly after the @echo off to avoid environment clutter

@Compo What if I need it before too?

@H.v.M. in order to help you with code prior to what you've submitted, we'd need to see that code. You're now asking for advice on how to do something we cannot see, or understand your delayed expansion 'need'. Currently, none of the code you have above needs variable expansion to be delayed, so we would need to understand its purpose within the code flow.

@Compo The script in question didn't need delayed expansion at all. I asked anyway for future use and for curiosity. Sorry if OP was misleading.

@H.v.M., not with set /p they aren't. I have added an example answer to hopefully demonstrate that.

Your problem is not the input nor the delayed expansion mode.
But you should avoid percent expansion after you enabled delayed expansion.
Delayed expansion of variables is always safe, independent of the variable content.
set /p var=... isn't a problem either.
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set a=caret^^.
set "b=caret^"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET x=
SET /P x=
SET y=a^^!b:c
SET "z=a^!b:c"
echo !a! !b!
echo !x! !y! !z!


Here's an example to show that there was no problem using Set /P with delayed variable expansion enabled, or with using a string enclosed between an exclamation mark, !, and a colon, :.
Please try this using your test string a!b:c:
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:InputPrompt
Set "x="
Set /P "x=Please provide your input string>"
If Not Defined x GoTo InputPrompt

Echo Non delayed variable syntax: %x%

Echo Delayed variable syntax: !x!

Pause

As you can see, the only issue, is clearly that you decided to use the echo command without using the delayed variable syntax. This is what jeb means, in their answer, by "you should avoid percent expansion after you enabled delayed expansion".
